# Global function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script that creates a div and adds a function that would remove this div on click, but it's not working.

```
function del(el) {
   $("#"+el).remove();
}


function create() {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var att = document.createAttribute("onclick"); 
    att.value = "del(this.id)";  
    element.setAttributeNode(att); 
    $(element).attr('id', "someID");
    document.getElementById("someContainer").appendChild(element);
}
```

Yes, yes, I KNOW this is not the best way to add a function, but I want to do it this way. 
Just FYI - after executing `create()` the DIV appears fine. I checked and it does have proper ID and `onclick="del(this.id)"` attribute, but after clicking on it nothing happens. I double checked and added `alert("I'm working")` to the onclick attribute later and that worked. I'm not getting any errors. In the past `.remove()` was working fine but now it doesn't (Maybe that's because of the way I'm adding a function this time)

EDIT: It appears that `del()` is not executed when clicking on div.

Comment: Please post your `HTML\`

Comment: ... And set up a Fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: What is `el` within the `function del()` coming back as? If the actual id is being passed in, you might be trying to access `id` property of a string value.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky `att.value = "del(this.id)"; `

Comment: Most likely, .remove isn't what isn't working. Do a bit more debugging.

Comment: does `this` points to the div element? I'm not sure :D

Comment: @KevinB I see what he is setting it to in the `create()` function, I was trying to confirm what `el` is actually coming out to in `del()`. I have a feeling string `"this.id"` it's not being interpreted as expected inside `del()`.

Comment: Okay, I checked some more and it appears that del() is not even executed. Why is that? @Roljhon this.id points to DIV's ID that is created.

Comment: probabaly because it isn't defined.

Comment: Is the `del` function in the global scope? Do you have multiple elements with the same ID? Does the element actually have an ID?

Comment: @squint Yes, it is.

Comment: @squint All IDs are unique, and after creating the div I checked and it does have that ID.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oa1zrbpw/ you're doing something wrong (well, besides the poor coding practices) that isn't obvious in the code you have provided. Please include enough information in your question to recreate the problem.

Comment: Are you even clicking on the div? are you sure?

Comment: @KevinB Of course.

Comment: Right clicking and inspecting it takes you to it?

Comment: @KevinB Oh, god I just figured it out. It turns out that another global function is preventing del() from being executed, I have to rewrite code, but I know what to do. The code in OP didn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @Vortic: Glad you figured it out. Just delete this question since the issue is not represented.

Comment: oh the joys of defining global vars/functions

Comment: How do I flag that this question doesn't need any more answers?

Comment: you could answer it, or delete it. but i dunno if it's eligible for deletion with an upvoted answer

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out myself, I tried to attach the function to the window Object, that made it work, but I'm not sure why the del() function didn't automatically attached to the window object? this is weird for me i guess hahaha

Comment: damn jsfiddle is the culprit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this posted with jQuery, but you're showing mostly Vanilla. As to your initial problem,

```js
function del(el) {
   $("#"+el).remove();
}

function create() {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var att = document.createAttribute("onclick"); 
    att.value = "del(this.id)";  
    element.setAttributeNode(att); 
    $(element).attr('id', "someID");
    document.getElementById("someContainer").appendChild(element);
$(element).html('<h1>DIV CREATED!</h1>').css('background-color', String.randColorHex());
}

create();
```

```css
#someContainer > div { height: 10em; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/String.randColorHex/0c9bb2ff/String.randColorHex.js"></script>
<div id="someContainer"></div>
```

> Seems to work fine.

My guess would be that you have an issue with creating multiple divs by with the same ID, or possibly a [**scope**](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) issue.

Here's a couple steps you might take to double check the issue if using Google Chrome Dev Tools:

- Open Console
- Double Check function 'del' is globally available and the method you expect it to be by simply typing `del`. If you get an error, then your method may be displaced.

  - Another way you could check would be put the following in your onClick: `try{console.debug(del);}catch(err){console.error('DEL DOES NOT EXIST!')}`

Once you've established the method is within scope, if still not working, try the following:

- Replace `$("#"+el).remove();` with `console.debug(el, $('#'+el))`
- This does a couple of things: It shows you that the Function is working, as well as gives you information of what's going on within.
- If the first part of the console message (`el`) is the ID you expect, then check the 2nd part (`$('#'+el)`).
- It should look something like: `[div:#someID]`
- Open it and check it's `length'. If`0`, then it did not find that element.
- If `1`, then remove should be working fine.  Put remove back in just above this console call, and ensure you now get a length of `0`

---

Just FYI, this is how to do what you're trying to do using jQuery.

```js
function create() {
 var container = $('#someContainer'), // get container
  // create div, everything in {} is an ATTR, then append it TO the container
  div = $('<div />', { id: 'someID' + container.children('div').length+1 }).appendTo(container);
 // just for visual, i use my own plugin to set a random background color
 div.css('background-color', String.randColorHex());
}

$(function() {
 $(document) // your click methods
  .on('click', '#btnCreate', create)
  .on('click', '#someContainer > div', function(e) { $(this).remove(); })
 
 //  trigger button once on load
 $('#btnCreate').trigger('click');
})
```

```css
#someContainer > div { height: 2em; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/String.randColorHex/0c9bb2ff/String.randColorHex.js"></script>
<button id="btnCreate">Create</button>
<hr />
<div id="someContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I mean, if the answer received upvotes, this terrible low quality question wouldn't be auto deleted. Feel free to edit the question into one that isn't low quality, but i don't think that is possible without the OP's help.

Comment: No, the IDs are always different. The code I provided here is a bit simpler than I'm using but in the actual code the ID is always different when creating a div. And besides, it's not working (as in my code) even if I create only one div, so I'm pretty sure that IDs are not a problem. Something's wrong with executing function. I'll try out your code and update if it's working.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: Non-answers that are better posted as comments (if at all) get down votes. Posting your favorite jQuery solution does nothing to address the problem.

Comment: ...even after your edit, it's still just a *"works for me"* answer.

Comment: @Vortic Try this, using Chrome, replace your remove code with `console.debug(el, $("#"+el))`. Then check your console when clicking. You should have 2 variables, the parameter passed, and a jQuery Element Object. Check the Object length, if 0, there's you're first problem. A couple things you can do here, check the property "selector" to see exactly what selector was used. It should look familiar. Second, if element was found, then when you first expand the element OBJ, the "0" indexed item is the element. Right click on it and click "Reveal in Elements panel"

Comment: @SpYk3HH *"EDIT: It appears that del() is not executed when clicking on div."*

Comment: @KevinB *I double checked and added alert("I'm working") to the onclick attribute later and that worked*  - Read all the way through. Sounds like it's working, just not the remove part.

Comment: well, no, it sounds like using an alert works, but `del` doesn't. that would indicate `del` is defined somewhere other than globally.

Comment: The problem lied somewhere entirely else and I solved it. I'm marking this answer as accepted anyway because of the all info you provided and I need to close this OP. Thanks.

Comment: @Vortic: Just FYI, you never need to "close" a question. If anyone ever badgers you about accepting an answer, just ignore them.